# Does windowsform have a calendar equivalent to that of one in asp.net?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

In my windowsform app I am using the calendar from the toolbox and using some sample code I found online to add some events behind the calendar however I get errors:

```
if (e.Day.Date == nf.Date)           
            {    
                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
```

which says e.Day does not exist in relation to the calendar object and same errors for other e. functions?

Answer (score 0):

The only standard calendar control available to Windows Forms applications is the `MonthCalendar` control. The `DateTimePicker` is also related, but it doesn't look like a calendar.

The `MonthCalendar` does not appear to provide any events with a `Day` property, so I suspect you've stumbled upon sample code for a non-standard calendar control. For the standard `MonthCalendar` you can get the selected date(s) via the `SelectionStart` and `SelectionEnd` properties. Unfortunately, if you were hoping to customize the appearance of the control with this sample code then I'm afraid you won't find anything similar on the standard version.